# Encontrar posición en un array

Tags: java

Supongamos que tengo el siguiente array:

```
List<String> list = ["Pepe","Paco","Lucas","Lucia","Stack"]
```

y quiero saber la posición que se encuentra "Lucas", que sería la posición 2, pero no quiero hacerlo con un for ya que si es un array de 1000 elementos es mucho, hay alguna forma de localizarlo más optima?

Comment: `list.indexOf("Lucas")`. Si hay más de un elemento con ese texto, sacará el primero que encuentre.

Comment: @lois6b aunque sea algo muy simple, tu comentario ameritaría una respuesta que sería la solución a la duda planteada en la pregunta. Para que la respuesta no tenga una sola línea, puedes indicar la descripción de este método, [citando la documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-). Ya me pasó una vez que diste la respuesta adecuada en comentarios, luego otro respondió y se llevó los puntos... Saludos.

Comment: @A.Cedano si, a veces me da pereza responder y no me importa que usen mi comentario para formar una respuesta. En este caso me entretuve buscando si existia una pregunta similar pero no la vi. Un saludo

Answer (score 9, accepted):

La función [`indexOf(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf-java.lang.Object-) nos devuelve la posición, en un `int`.

- Si hubiera múltiples ocurrencias del elemento, devolvería el primero.
- En el caso de que el `String` no exista se devuelve un `-1`.

Otra función similar es `lastIndexOf()`. Funcionaría igual, salvo que en el caso de múltiples ocurrencias, devolveria el índice del la última coincidencia.

En tu código quedaría:

```
List<String> list = ["Pepe","Paco","Lucas","Lucia","Stack"]
int indiceLucas =  list.indexOf("Lucas"); // => 2
```

Comment: Notar que a pesar de ser más simple y legible, no es mas rapido que un `for`, un `indexOf` sigue siendo una búsqueda secuencial

Comment: @Klaimmore si, estuve viendo el código que usa `indexOf` y es iterativo igual.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, bueno aunque tarde lo mismo aunque por dentro el indexof haga el for, pero son menos lineas de código que tengo que escribir

Comment: @sirdaiz intenté encontrar algun articulo sobre diferencias entre `for loop` y `indexOf`. En la implementacion de `indexOf` pese a ser iterativa, tiene comparaciones de `char` y comparan primera letra de cada elemneto, y si hay coincidencia buscan más alla. Quiza sea asi algo más rapido que comparar cadena con cadena de cada elemento...